# Зачем нужен "shadow space" при использовании "fastcall"?

Tags: ассемблер, cpu, процессор

Если суть "fastcall" заключается в передаче первых параметров через регистры, не обращаясь к стеку - для оптимизации работы CPU. Тогда я не вижу смысла в "shadow space", если он все равно запишет параметры в стек - ради работающих точек останова. Я новичок и для моего понимания оба описанных метода взаимо-ирациональны.

Почему процессоры все равно используют fastcall одновременно с shadow space? Не проще ли исключить их обоих?

Comment: что ты имеешь в виду под «fastcall»? для одноимённого соглашения о вызовах в win под x86 я не вижу ни одного упоминания о «shadow space»...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В зависимости от соглашения о `fastcall` в регистр записывается первые `n` параметров, тем не менее их пространство в стеке зарезервировано. Вызывающий не может записать ничего в `shadow space`, но оно доступно для вызываемого, к примеру, если ему нужно сохранить параметры для вызова другой функции